# PHP Checking if a remote file exists always returns false

Tags: php

For some reason when I try to get the status of the path from a remote server, it keeps returning false. My code is supposed to run a bash script from a remote server on button click and output to the webpage. My code works and I can successfully output the bash script back to the web page, however, when I add the conditional to check if the file exists it goes to the else statement. I know my `$sftp` is good because it doesn't throw an exception.

```
<?php
$gwUser = 'user';
$gwPwd = 'pwd';
$path = '/my/path/to/directory/bash.sh';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($gateway, 22)) {
       ssh2_auth_password($connection, $gwUser, $gwPwd);
       $sftp = @ssh2_sftp($connection);
       if (!$sftp) throw new Exception("Could not initialize SFTP subsystem."); 
       $fileExists = file_exists('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . $path); //this returns "file doesn't exist" 
       if($fileExists) {
           echo "the file exists";
       } else {
           echo "the file doesn't exist: " . $fileExists;
       }
       (code omitted for simplicity)
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I can vouch for this issue happening with both `file_exists` and `is_dir`. I have two servers running the same code. One returns true from `file_exists` and one returns false. I have not yet been able to figure out why. Same version of PHP & openssl on both. Possible bug here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71047